# Swift: ViewController Error in webView project

Tags: uiwebview, swift

Writing a simple app in Xcode 6 in Swift.

```
class htmlViewController : UIViewController 
{
    @IBOutlet var webbb: UIWebView
}

class ViewController: UIViewController 
{
    override func viewDidLoad() 
    {
        let url = NSURL(string: "http://apple.com")
        let reqq = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
        self.webbb.loadView(reqq)
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

Have some error on line "self.webbb.loadView(reqq)":

> ViewController does not have a member named WebView.

Any ideas?

P.S. Sorry for noob question! :-)

Comment: The code you posted is missing a }. Not sure if that's your problem though.

Comment: Don't start a class name with a small letter ("htmlViewController"). And why do we have two classes here?

Answer (score 8):

for load a web page in a UIWebView just use this code :

```
@IBOutlet var web1 : UIWebView


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var url = NSURL(string: "http://www.google.com")
    var request = NSURLRequest(URL: url)

    web1.loadRequest(request)

}
```

and if you want to load a page from main bundle use this code :

```
@IBOutlet var web1 : UIWebView

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("pageName", ofType: "html"))

    //var url = NSURL(string: "http://www.google.com")

    var request = NSURLRequest(URL: url)

    web1.loadRequest(request)

}
```

Comment: note that the var 'url' must be force unwrapped, like `var request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)`

Answer (score 1):

You defined `webbb` in a class called `htmlViewController` but you're adding functionality to another subclass called `ViewController`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is that the `ViewController` class has no access to the `webbb` variable. There are a few solutions for this problem.

**Solution 1:**

When you define the `ViewController` class make the Superclass `htmlViewController`. That would look like this:

```
class ViewController: htmlViewController{...}
```

This means that the `ViewController` class will inherit from the `htmlViewController` class. This allows you to access variables and functions from the `htmlViewController` class. You can read more about inheritance and swift in [this document](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Inheritance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH17-XID_251).

---

**Solution 2:**

Why not bring the `webbb` variable into the `ViewController` class? I would recommend doing this if you do not plan on using the `htmlViewController` class anywhere else. Here is an example

```
class ViewController: htmlViewController{
    @IBOutlet var webbb: UIWebView
    //Do everything else.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You also need to add a ! after UIWebView when you are defining it.